# Can (in any ways) a subquery modify the database in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, subquery

- A command , starting with `SELECT`, cannot modify the database.

Is above statement always true, or are there exceptions?

Maybe in other words, can we create subqueries which include `update` command?

Comment: It depends on the database.  Some databases support the `into` clause, which definitely modifies the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am asking this question for one reason: "If I start a transaction and execute only queries which starts with `select `, does it matter if I `commit` or `rollback`?". In this case I think it matters.

Comment: @serdar I think it won't matter. Since commit and rollback are used for applying / removing changes made to the DB. If you have a `SELECT .. INTO` which you `commit` or issue a `rollback`, then that would be considered a change that would be affected by the `commit` or `rollback`, but if it is a simple `SELECT FROM .. ` then running a `commit` or `rollback` won't have any change on the DB.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . Postgres allows `update`, `delete`, and `insert` in queries that are essentially `select`.  These are allowed in CTEs and provide the functionality that `OUTPUT` or `RETURNING` do in other databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Today has been a good day to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any RDMBS that has AFTER | INSTEAD OF Select Triggers implemented, but that would be the situation where SELECT can indirectly modify a database.

There could also be an auditing set up on your server, that tracks SELECT statements. For example in Oracle you have [DBMS_FGA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_fga.htm) package, that you could use to essentially create ON SELECT Trigger, by creating a policy without `audit_condition` parameter. This will cause an event to fire on every select, and a procedure that modifies a database to be executed. I don't know about transactions in this case, but I think that rollback doesn't affect auditing, otherwise it will be simple to cheat it :).

Another example (Sql Server):

```
Select * from 
OPENQUERY(servername, 'EXEC uspGetRows')
```

`uspGetRows` procedure can do a bunch of other stuff in addition to returning rows.

I figure that you rather had in mind explicit modifications, through insert/update/delete statements "merged" with select, but I never heard of something like this. So those are just two examples of situations similiar to INSERT..INTO from comments.

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory answer. Very good approach indeed.